# Recovering data about custom post and taxonomy types

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-taxonomy

I recently had an incident where my work was overwritten on our server, which included code in the functions.php file of our theme to create several new custom post and taxonomy types. The posts and taxonomies they created are still in the site, but I no longer have any way of seeing how they were created so I can use them in WP queries. Is there any way of viewing this data still? I'm mainly hoping to write a tax_query for a custom taxonomy as a part of a WP Query on one of our pages to differentiate between posts that do and don't belong to that specific custom taxonomy.

Comment: You can view your data using phpmyadmin which your host should have available in your control panel. The posts will be in the wp-posts table with their post_type. Here's the database diagram https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Database_Diagram.    You can then write a WP query to pull out the data by post type with/without taxonomy terms.

Comment: Your host should also have backups and should be able to retrieve the files for you.